# Kill a docker container using awk command in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, awk, gitlab-ci

I would like to use awk in gitlab-ci.yml to kill a docker container. However, awk does not work as expected.
For example, I want to kill a docker container called ADockerContainer using awk. Therefore I use the following command:

```
docker kill $(docker ps | grep ADockerContainer | awk '{print $1}')
```

After the execution of the command, I get:

```
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does `docker ps | grep ADockerContainer | awk '{print $1}'` return you a valid process ID

Comment: I think the problem is the $() part of the command. It looks like gitlab somehow is confusing it with gitlab ci variables.

Comment: I found a workaround:
 containerName=`docker ps -q --filter="name= ADockerContainer"`
&& `docker kill $containerName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker kill` (and other commands) will take the container name directly, so you don't need any sort of command substitution here.  It's enough to run

```bash
docker kill AContainerName
```